# Identifier is undefined on initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am new to C++ Programming. I am using a cpp file to hold various variables and I am a bit concerned I am doing something wrong here. I have a .cpp file that only holds some variables.

```
    #include "Variables.h"

    using namespace::std;

    char ListItem[260] = "<Choose Location>";
    string sqlDirectiveMessage = "";
    int locationIndex = -1;
    int selectionIndex = 0;
    int dataGatheredFromIndex = 0;
    SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
```

and Variables.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <string>

using namespace::std;

extern char ListItem[];
extern string sqlDirectiveMessage;
extern int locationIndex;
extern int selectionIndex;
extern int dataGatheredFromIndex;

extern SQLCHAR retconstring[1024];
```

Piece of relevant code:

```
    case IDC_ADD:
    {
        int test = 0;
        HWND listbox = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LIST3);
        selectionIndex = (int)SendMessage(listbox, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
        dataGatheredFromIndex = (int)SendMessage(listbox, LB_GETITEMDATA, selectionIndex, 0);

    }
    break;
```

now in this case, if I do a Watch in VS 2017 on a few variables, selectionIndex and locationIndex seems to work fine, test is undefined and so is dataGatheredFromIndex.. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `test` is a local variable. It might have been optimized out and the assignment is not necessary. Do you use a configuration where optimization is enabled (AKA Release configuration)?

Comment: You are right I am running in release Config.

Comment: Changing the config to debug seems to fix the problem. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can optimize code so that operations are omitted or ordered differently. The optimization is typically enabled in a Release build configuration.

The variable `test` in your code is a victim of such optimization because no code can read it back. You should ignore variable values if your code doesn't access it if optimization is turned on.

Comment: Note that you should be able to bypass this optimization by marking the variable as `volatile`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as intended when I change the configuration. I am still having trouble getting my data from my list box but that is out of the scope of this question. Thanks!